# Finding Coordinates of a Peak on a Plot

Tags: list-manipulation, peak-detection

I have plotted a graph from a CSV file which consists of two columns of data *Time* and *Intensity*. I simply want to find the time where the intensity is largest.

This code:

```
MaxIntensity = Max[Data[[All, 2]]]
```

outputs the correct value for the peak y axis value.

However, this code:

```
Position[Data[[All, 1]], MaxIntensity]
```

just outputs `{}`.

Also, this code:

```
Position[Data, MaxIntensity]
```

outputs `{{429, 2}}`.

Looking at the CSV file in a text editor the `429` is the line number where the peak value occurs, but I can't figure out what that `2` means and I can't use that output to pick out the corresponding time for index `429`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: The "2" means it comes from the second column, i.e. you're finding the position of the intensity in a 2D list.

Comment: How can I extract the Row number only then so I can use that further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest modification to your already existing approach is this:

```
data = {{0, 98}, {1, 100}, {2, 110}, {3, 99}, {4, 100}}

(* ==> {{0, 98}, {1, 100}, {2, 110}, {3, 99}, {4, 100}} *)

maxIntensity = Max[data[[All, 2]]]

(* ==> 110 *)

First@Flatten[Position[data, {_, maxIntensity}]]

(* ==> 3 *)
```

Here, I used `Position` on `data` directly, but with a pattern in which the first entry of the pair `{_, maxIntensity}` means that it is irrelevant for the position search. Have a look at [`Blank`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Blank.html). The `First@Flatten` is needed because `Position` could return more than one match, and I assume you only want the first match. If you want all of them, just omit `First`.

There are also other approaches. For example, you could use [`Ordering`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Ordering.html):

```
Ordering[data, 1, #1[[2]] > #2[[2]] &]

(* ==> {3} *)
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks!